# Issue in validation

Tags: flutter

I am trying to navigate from one page to another by following validation but validation is not working even if textfield is empty it is navigating to another page How can I fix this please help
Here is the code :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoxeT.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
   final GlobalKey<FormState> formKeyEditProfile = GlobalKey<FormState>();
   bool _autovalidate = false;
                
                onTap: () async {
                  if (formKeyEditProfile.currentState.validate()) {
                    formKeyEditProfile.currentState.save();
                    _autovalidate = false;
                    await this.updateProfile();
                  } else {
                    if (this.mounted) setState(() =>  _autovalidate = true);
                  }
                }
```